# Controlling VLC via telnet with python script

Tags: python, telnet, vlc

So I have this script I can't get working. I have verified it's the script, as I can cmd->telnet to localhost 4212 and are able to change vlc there(like next and stop).

But the script doesn't give any errors either. I have python installed:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import telnetlib

cmd = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
tn = telnetlib.Telnet("localhost", 4212)
tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write("admin\n")
tn.read_until("> ")
tn.write(cmd + "\n")
tn.close()
```

Comment: what's the command you used to launch this script? clearly it needs an argument of some sort to do whatever you want.

Comment: I'm doing it via VoiceAttack. But normally it would be f,ex, to clear the playlist: >vlc_command.py clear